# How do I implement nested arraylist in java?

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I want to create a custom collection something like :

```
{"2011-10-27": {object1 , object2 , ...}  , "2011-10-28" : {object n , object n+1 , ..}}
```

And for this matter I think arraylist can satisfy my requirement but I don't know how I'm able to implement a  nested arraylist in java.

If you think for my purpose arraylist is not suitable what kind of collection set do I have to use in java?

regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using a `Map`, in which you can store key-value pairs. See the [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/index.html) javadoc.

Comment: +1 this is the correct method of storing key-value pairs in java. @austin, it would look like this: `Map<String,ArrayList> kv = new HashMap<String,ArrayList>();`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like what you are looking for is a `Map`:

```
Map<Date, Set<Object>> map = new HashMap<Date, Set<Object>>();

map.put(new Date(), new HashSet<Object>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3)));
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're showing looks more like a Map of Lists:

```
Map<String,List>> map = new HashMap<String,List>>();
```

then you can populate each one with:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add(object1);
map.put("2001-01-10",list);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a `Map` storing a `String` as the key, with each key mapping to an `ArrayList`.

```
        Map<String,ArrayList> mp=new HashMap<String, ArrayList>();
        ArrayList<String>newarray = new ArrayList<String>();
        newarray.add("hello");
        mp.put("2011-10-97", newarray);
```

Depending on what kind of object you want to store in the `ArrayList`, you can change the type accordingly, I've left it as a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) coupled to an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) :

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>> myMap = new  HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>>();
ArrayList<Object> myList = new ArrayList<Object>();
myList.add(anObject);
myMap.put("2011-10-27", myList);
```

You can also use a `Date` instead of String for the `HashMap` key.

In fact, instead of using `HashMap` and `ArrayList`, you can use any combination of classes implementing the [`Map` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and the [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) or [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) interface